# Webkit - fix positioned elements seem to have inherent stacking context

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

Encountered this "bug" in Chrome when working with [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) and a fixed header.

I'll keep this short and simple, I want to place an absolute positioned element in front of another element, but the two are in separate fix positioned containers. Here's the Code:

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100px;
}

.elm {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.elm-back {
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    background: teal;
}

.elm-front {
    z-index: 2;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-1">
    <div class="elm elm-front"></div>
</div>
<div class="container container-2">
    <div class="elm elm-back"></div>
</div>

<div class="container fixed container-1">
    <div class="elm elm-front"></div>
</div>
<div class="container fixed container-2">
    <div class="elm elm-back"></div>
</div>
```

The first two boxes are inside absolute positioned containers, the other two are inside fix positioned ones.

Firefox and IE both handle it as expected (image below).

[image: Example in Firefox and IE]

While Chrome and Safari do the following:

[image: Example in Webkit]

Does someone know, e.g. have a source on why exactly this happens and hopefully a solution or workaround? I already tried using `transform: translateZ(0)`, the only thing I can achieve with that is that the first two elements behave like the other two, but I want it the other way around.

Comment: It may have something to do with this [google dev article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements).

Comment: Note that in the meantime FF seems to behave the same as chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You styled theirs containers as fixed, so they Z indexed to straight document - **the containers**. while the first group is Z indexed also to the document (because there isn't any relative parent in-between) but in the 1st is the **elements** that get styled so they Z indexed properly.

The browsers render's each of containers fixed position and put them each on other by they own algorithm, so if you want to fix it just let the browser know the Z index that you want for the containers as well:

```
.container-1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.container-2 {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

or to put each absolute DIVs together from first so they will be Z-indexed to the same parent.